# Puppet apach::vhost ssl_cert, ssl_key are not being created

Tags: apache, ssl, puppet

Im trying to puppetize a server, and in the .pp apache config file I have:

```
apache::vhost { "000-default-ssl":
    servername       => "$sitename",
    serveraliases    => ["$sitename"],
    serveradmin      => 'webmaster@localhost',
    port             => '443',
    docroot          => "/path/to/docroot",
    access_log_file  => 'ssl-access.log',
    error_log_file   => 'ssl-error.log',
    ssl              => true,
    ssl_cert         => '/data/ssl/www/365_acdsee_com.crt',
    ssl_key          => '/data/ssl/www/365_acdsee_com.key',
    #...morecode...
  }
```

And when I run it, the file 000-default-ssl.conf is made and everything, but then when i look in /data/ssl/www/ it's empty. neither 365_acdsee_com.crt, or 365_acdsee_com.key are there.

So my question is: Is declaring the lines ssl_key and ssl_cert supposed to create the certificate and key, or do I have to have something else that generates them, and if not why isnt it making the files???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is declaring the lines ssl_key and ssl_cert supposed to create the certificate and key ?

No. It will not generate cert and/or key. You have to generate these files manually or get from some cert provider.

Look at the source code of [vhost.pp](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/vhost.pp). These values are used to generate config file `${priority_real}${filename}.conf`, from the [_ssl.erb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/vhost/_ssl.erb)

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch. Since I'm only testing I just commented out the ssl_key and ssl_cert, so it would generate a default key and certificate for me.